# How to display the name of the user instead of id. Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello as the title says I'm not sure why my code is not showing the "First Name" for a user but it shows the ID only I have tried to do a lot of different methods to solve this but I'm rather a beginner in laravel so I thought It would be best if I asked for help by now

To explain a little the field "recieverID" is a foreign key of the table Users that shows the ID of the users

So here is the model named "Remark"

```
class Remark extends Model
{
 protected $guarded =[];

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
}
```

This is the Remark Controller

```
public function index()
{

    if(Auth::guard('admin')->check())
    {
        $users = User::all();
        $remarks = Remark::latest()->get();
    return view('admin.remark.index', compact('users'),compact('remarks'));
    }
```

It has more code under it but I only need it for this part, I added the $users and compact users because I tried to add 2 foreach loops on the view to see how it looks but it didn't quite work as i thought it might

This is the view I want to show the Name instead of the ID

```
@foreach($remarks as $remark)
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{$remark->recieverID->user->first_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$remark->title}}</td>
                        <td>{{$remark->subject}}</td>
                        <td>{{$remark->message}}</td>
                        <td>{{$remark->sender}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: I got this error `Call to a member function user() on integer `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to change your relationship as below. If you don't pass `foreign key` then it assumes that you have foreign key as(**user_id**) in the table. but you have **recieverID** in the table. So, you need to define it.

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'recieverID','id');
}
```

Now you can add it blade file.

```
<td>{{$remark->user->first_name}}</td>
```

Comment: Wow this worked thank you so much might I ask if its possible to know why this fixed it?